# Is adding too many people/characters to a story bad?

Tags: characters, screenwriting

im building a world for a screenplay and i would like to have some main characters I have already made some character profiles for some of them but i was wondering whether or not if adding too many characters will make the storyline confusing. I want to make 6 main characters, 24 secondary characters and 70 tertiary characters that wouldn't have large speaking roles. they would show up in an "episode" or "chapter" but that's it.

Comment: That number of players may also depend on how big your world will be ! When there's all kinds of different places where people will be, you'll need more characters. When it's small, you can do with a only a few. I find the DUST series on YT an example of extreme low budget, agreeable for me (as a viewer) and in most episodes, there are only 3-6 people, say 1-2 main characters, a few secundary and a few "figurants". Except when the aliens land of course :)

Comment: Looks like the Worldbuilding mods migrated this here without checking to see if you'd reposted it yourself, so now we have two copies of the same question. I've merged them together for you, just so all the answers are in one place.

Comment: YOu question is titled illogically.  Adding too many or too much of anything to a story is bad (for the story).  If that amount was not bad for the story, it wouldn't be "too many", it would be "about the right number".  As long as your title is "Is adding too many people/characters to a story bad?" the answer will have to be yes.  Because "too many" is always bad by definition.   This answer to your title has nothing to do with the answer to the body of your question.

Comment: You are putting the cart before the horse. Don't go hiring the actors until the story is written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Context and organization is important. Your highschool class of 200 people might be more memorable than a college lecture hall of 100.

Think about how you would remember all your classmates names. Or if you're from a large family, think about how you would recall your different cousins. In your mind you're organizing and anchoring to something, perhaps a common teacher, common parties, or which two cousins are from Montana, which one was the engineer, etc. How would you present secondary characters in your screenplay in a manner that helps your audience remember them?

I recently had this discussion with my DM for D&D who was upset that we couldn't keep up with his story. Some party members expressed it was because there were too many characters and groups, he rightly pointed out that in absolute terms it was a lot less than his previous campaign in which we were much more engaged and able to follow. The biggest difference I think, was because in the new campaign he was all over the place. Every group is siloed, and there's no continuous or cohesive story. One week its Evil group A another week is Evil group B, then Group C, D, and so on. 2 months later its a sub-section of Evil Group A but the original Evil group A members or activities never came up. That is completely disorganized.

So what I told him was it doesn't matter so much in absolute terms how many characters there are, there needs to be something for us the players (or for you, audiences) to anchor each character's association with. Every member of Evil Group A or subsection 123 should consistently reference to a leader, cause, ideology to keep them as a collective memorable. This helps the player to trigger what they remember about Group A and then can start recalling a relationship tree of cahracters associated with Group A. Having multiple groups and sub groups doing seemlingly disjointed activities (His goal as the DM was to keep their motives a mystery until we the players find out) gives us nothing to anchor to, nothing to help with memory recall, because there was nothing really memorable or reference to unless we are to take out a notepad and write everything down and review like an actual real life detective, and that's simply not how players in a game or audiences of a TV show operate.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

for a small 21 minutes episode that's a lot of characters, for a small series of 24 episodes that's kind of an average or below average amount of characters, for a big movie it is very small. for a large series, anything below 200 characters is considered very little UNLESS it's a sitcom or any other form of comedy.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's such a thing as too many characters. Especially tertiary characters. A good amount of small side-characters, if fleshed out, can make your world feel more much more alive.

However, it has to make sense that your POV character would know these tertiaries. If they wouldn't know them, then it's like if you dialled a random telephone number and said, "Hey Megan, wanna go to dinner tonight?" How do you know her name?

Of course, if you can't do that, you can have the POV meet the side-character along with the reader, so that your reader learns about them with the POV character.

Answer (score 0):

Screenplays are extremely time and space constrained.

Every character you add takes up space and time, and dilutes the space and time of other characters in your story.

So yes, adding too many characters to a story is bad, in the same way adding too much water to your lemonade is bad; dilution reduces flavor.

Ultimately it depends on how much space and time you have. A typical screenplay is 110 pages, 110 minutes, and cannot support a huge cast of characters with lines.

Your question says a "screenplay", but then "episodes" or "chapters". If you mean a series or franchise, obviously you have a lot more leeway with the number of characters, many series have a new developed character for a few episodes; Buffy The Vampire Slayer introduced a powerful new villain, very well developed, for every season.

But even then, since your main characters may develop in unexpected ways, it might be better to leave the invention of those new characters until later.

It just depends on how much real estate you have. It is better to have a few well developed characters we like, than a ton of underdeveloped characters we barely know.

Take your clue from existing comparable productions; either individual movies or series or franchises. Fit the size of your cast (and your story) to the real estate you have.